# Pandas Dataframe: groupby id to find max column value and return corresponding value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by, max

I have a large dataframe with different food entries. Each food has one nutrient (A, B, C, D) with a corresponding value for that nutrient in another column.
I want to define a function which takes a specific nutrient as an argument and returns the **name of the food** with the highest nutrient value. If the argument does not exist, it should return 'Sorry, {requested nutrient} not found'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.99, 0.87, 0.58, 0.66, 0.62, 0.81, 0.63, 0.71, 0.77, 0.73, 0.69, 0.61, 0.92, 0.49],
               list('DAABBBBABCBDDD'),
               ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'lemon', 'grape', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'spam', 'fish', 'bread',
                'salad', 'milk', 'soda', 'juice'],
               ['***', '**', '****', '*', '***', '*', '**', '***', '*', '*', '****', '**', '**', '****']]).T
df.columns = ['value', 'nutrient', 'food', 'price']
```

I have tried the following:

```
def food_for_nutrient(lookup_nutrient, dataframe=df):
    max_values = dataframe.groupby(['nutrient'])['value'].max()
    result = max_values[lookup_nutrient]
    return print(result)
```

It seems to identify the max values of the nutrients correctly but it returns only the nutrient value. I need the corresponding str from column **food**.
For instance, if I give the following argument

```
food_for_nutrient('A‘)
```

My desired output is:

```
banana
```

My second problem is that my **if statement** doesn't work. It always returns **else**

```
def food_for_nutrient(lookup_nutrient, dataframe=df):
    max_values = dataframe.groupby(['nutrient'])['value'].max()
    if lookup_nutrient in dataframe['nutrient']:
        result = max_values[lookup_nutrient]
        return print(result)
    else:
        return print(f'Sorry, {lookup_nutrient} not found.')

food_for_nutrient('A')
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why return `spam` instead of `banana`?

Comment: Thanks @richardec, I corrected the mistake.

Comment: Ok, let me update my answer

Comment: check my answer now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def food_for_nutrient(lookup_nutrient):
    try:
        return df[df['nutrient'] == lookup_nutrient].set_index('food')['value'].astype(float).idxmax()
    except ValueError:
        return f'Sorry, {lookup_nutrient} not found.'
```

Output:

```
>>> food_for_nutrient('A')
'banana'

>>> food_for_nutrient('B')
'cheese'

>>> food_for_nutrient('C')
'bread'

>>> food_for_nutrient('D')
'apple'

>>> food_for_nutrient('E')
'Sorry, E not found.'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code works but I am not sure the results are correct. As you said, should ’A’ not return ’banana’? Same goes for B=cheese, D=apple